# Small Team : Is it better to work on specefic objects, or on specific layers?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, task

I'm a leader of a small team, and I want some advice of how to divide tasks on developers of a n-tier business software.

Scenario A:

each developer has some specific objects to build at all layers (DB, DAL,BL, GUI...)

Scenario B:

each developer has a certain domain of layers to work on at any object !!

Scenario C:

each developer work on anything with a specific schedule !!

any advice would help!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should take into account the knowledge skills and experience of each of your team members and divide the work accordingly.

If your design is correctly layered and decomposed then there should be no problem for anyone as regards waiting on someone else since they can easily stub out the missing class(es) and continue on their work.

If time permits, you may want to assign some portions of the work to members who are not familiar with certain areas of the system (either business domain or programming related) so they can learn those areas and in time not only become well rounded as programmers but the business will benefit by having more the one team member being familiar with various areas of the system as well as having a deep understanding on the business domain. So it's win-win for everyone (with an investment of time).